# Is possible to connect a Wiimote to a USB Port for power?

Tags: nintendo-wii, wii-u, wiimote

I play games that only require you to point at the screen, no abrupt movements like dance games for example. Because of this, I always have the controller in close proximity to the TV, Console (Wii or Wii U) or my PC.

I was wondering if is possible to connect the Wiimote directly to a USB Port so I don't have to change the batteries that often.

Comment: I tried making a Voltage Divider with the Wii U USB Port and two resistors (15k and 10k for 3V). That didn't worked, so the controller might need to "sense" the charge of the batteries.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no.

Longer answer probably

At one point I had a third party, rechargeable battery pack that had a usb port on the back, it likely worked while plugged in but I have misplaced it and cannot try it.

You can probably cut a usb cable and wire it into the back of the controller. Drill a small hole in the battery cover for the wire. A resistor divider (as suggested in the comments) probably won't work. You need a buck converter instead. if you dont mind potentially frying a controller you could just try and hook the 5 volts a usb cord supplies directly to the battery terminals and It might work, but I would not suggest that. Additionally I have not tried but you may be able to power the controller through the expansion port by splicing in a usb wire and using a buck converter.